# PayPal Monthly Balance with PHP?

Tags: php, paypal

Is it possible to get this month's PayPal balance in PHP? If so, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: To find out, you can send $5 to my Paypal account.  :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they offer SOAP services, according to their [documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks#SOAP)

But there is some requirements.

Next time I suggest to search about API.  Usually if a company offer a way to retrieve a information ( paypal balance, tweets on twitter,  message on facebook, etc) they will offer a API.

So in your case, a google search with term like "Paypal API php" will help you